# What's the name of the <type> syntax?

Tags: c#, syntax

I've probably written the title incorrectly here, but anyway... When you create, for example, a list in C#

```
List<int> list;
```

What is the name of the operator/syntax(?) where you specify the type between the angled-brackets?

Comment: parameters for generic class/method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called [Generic parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) for the `List<T>` class.

Comment: And "List<int>" is called a specialization of the generic List<T>

Comment: @Larry - really? I'm aware of the concept of specialization in e.g C++ templates, but such a concept doesn't exist in C#/CLR generics, does it? And, in fact, I just searched C# language spec (4.0), and the word "specialization" doesn't occur at all.

Comment: When I talk to the CLR developers about it, that's how they describe it.  
How does the C# language spec describe the construct? Note that because the CLR implements true generics (which are different from templates), List<int> isn't a specific language construct (unlike template specializations which are).  So it's possible that the language specification doesn't describe it because as a construct it doesn't exist in the language.

Comment: @Larry - I think the C# spec refers to it as a constructed type (if I'm reading it right). I don't have a CLR spec handy at the moment. I write C# in my spare time, I'm paid to write VB, so I could have things wrong.

Comment: @Larry: "Specialization" doesn't show up in the CLI spec (ECMA-335) either, so it must be some internal jargon rather than standard nomenclature.

Comment: @$@$ I just checked my email again and I was wrong.  The proper term is a 'closed generic' (for List<int>) and "open generic" (for List<T>).

Comment: Protocol question: I cannot edit my original (incorrect) comment, but I can delete it.  Should I delete the comment (thus rendering the other comments on this answer unintelligible) or leave it (thus hiding the correct answer under the fold).

Comment: @Larry - problem solved (hopefully) - I just upvoted your correction, so it should move up.